# Can I rename a MySQL Column without knowing the existing column name?

Tags: mysql, alter-table, information-schema

I'm writing a series of MySQL queries to manipulate data in tables.  I've got one table that is automatically generated by a system outside my control.  When I get it, the table has several columns:

ID, Name, Date, Title and a column containing decimal values.

Each time the table is automatically generated by the external system, it names the value containing the decimal values with the current date.  For now, the column is called "16_Jul_17", as that is the last day the system was run.

I need a reliable way to query the table (and rename the column), without needing to know the current name of the decimal value column.  Is there a way to do one of the following options:

1. Rename the decimal value column without knowing the name of the column
2. I can use information_schema to get the name, but then how do I use that to rename the column

Comment: I should note that the queries are performed within a data warehousing tool and I'm not entirely sure of the capabilities in terms of what mysql commands it will accept, but have found that it accepts a very large majority of the commands that I've tried to date.

Comment: Whomever designed that external system that names columns by the date deserves to get [pantsed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debagging).

Comment: Use dynamic SQL  query the info schema's to get the column names of the table not in (ID, name, date, title).  If 1 column remains that's the column name you need to alter.  if more than 1 then the structure changed and you need to error out asking what to do (as you need to add a new column to the not in)

Comment: @BillKarwin - Amen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround that works for me.  I don't know how applicable it is in general, but for my application, it works like a charm.
Since I know the order of the columns in the table from the external source, I simply use a UNION ALL, as follows:

```
Select 'Id', 'Name', 'Date', 'Title', 0.00 AS 'Value' LIMIT 0
UNION ALL
Select * from original_table
```

MySQL uses the values as column names except where explicitly aliased. 
Note that the `LIMIT 0` is required so that you don't have a dummy row.

Answer (score 2):

You can rename columns with the `ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN` statement, but you must know the name of the column first.

You'll have to use `DESCRIBE <tablename>` or query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the name and data types of the columns in the table.

Once you get the name of the column, you can format a string for the `ALTER TABLE` statement for that column. You should do this with application code.

Comment: Thanks, Bill!  The Alter Table statement is where I've gotten stuck, simply because the application I'm using doesn't have any application code capability...  Just a series of MySQL queries.
I've found another workaround though...  Since I know the order of the columns in the table, I simply use a UNION ALL command, as follows:
Select 'Id', 'Name', 'Date', 'Title', 0.00 AS 'Value'
UNION ALL
Select * from *originaltable*

I then follow that with a second query selecting all from the first query WHERE `Id`!='Id'

It feels like a hack, but it works!

Comment: Wow, that is a hack, but it does work. That application must be maddening to work with.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position N that columns was defined, you can use a query to recover the N-column name:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TBL_NAME'
AND ORDINAL_POSITION = POSITION_YOUR_COLUMN
```

After, you can change this column specifically manually (by ALTER TABLE) or automatically by script (generate ALTER in shell, python, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I use a stored procedure:

```
create procedure renamecolumn(in theTable varchar(128), in oldColumn varchar(128), in newColumn varchar(128)) begin
  set @oldType := (select 
    concat(COLUMN_TYPE,
    if(IS_NULLABLE="NO"," not null",""),
    if(COLUMN_DEFAULT is not null,concat(" default ",if(DATA_TYPE!="int","'",""),COLUMN_DEFAULT,if(DATA_TYPE!="int","'","")),""),
    if(COLUMN_KEY="PRI"," primary key","")," ",EXTRA) from information_schema.columns 
  where table_name = theTable and column_name = oldColumn and table_schema = database());

  set @exist := (select count(*) from information_schema.columns 
                 where table_name = theTable and column_name = newColumn and table_schema = database());
  set @alterstmt   := (select concat("alter table " ,theTable, " change column ", oldcolumn, " ", newColumn, " ", @oldType));
  set @warningstmt := (select concat("a column with the name '" ,newColumn, "' already exists in ", theTable));
  set @sqlstmt     := if( @exist > 0, 'select @warningstmt as warning', @alterstmt);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstmt;
  EXECUTE stmt;
end;
```