# Convert Domain Calculus into (Postgre-)SQL

Tags: sql, domain-calculus

Let there be a table `Person` with attributes (columns) `Name` and `Age`.

Given the following expression in Domain Calculus:
`{[name] | ∃ age (Person(name,age) ∧ age≥18)}`

I want to create the corresponding SQL query.

Is it possible (not asking if it is good practice) to create such an SQL query (not only in this specific case) **WITHOUT** knowing the database schema? So I do not need to know that the table `Person` has the columns named `Name` and `Age`.

I have thought about accessing the table through column indices, but I am confused.

Comment: Define "convert" & "corresponding". (Same function of inputs? Certain parallel structure?) What SQL are you able to write? How can you relate it to answering this question? How is this even a practical programming problem if you're not stopped from writing SQL? [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [help/on-topic] [Help] PS Yes-or-no questions including "is it possible" are poor Q&A, what do you really want to know?

Comment: When defining aliases in FROM a new column name list can be given.

Comment: Which SQL/DBMS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I rename a MySQL Column without knowing the existing column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175249/can-i-rename-a-mysql-column-without-knowing-the-existing-column-name)

Comment: „Convert“ & „corresponding“ as defined by the english language. I have a expression set in domain calculus, I want a SQL query that returns the same result.

Comment: We use PostgreSQL, as indicated by the title of the question

Comment: No, I don’t think aliases will help, since I do not know the existing column names

Comment: @philipxy That might actually help. I‘ll look into it. But I cannot write two separate SQL Queries unfortunately

Comment: Please tag appropriately & don't put something only in the title. Please clarify via edits, not comments. The everyday words you used mean nothing in detail. I already gave 2 different things it could be referring to before you wrote your comment in reply. Use enough words to say what you mean, not just a vague word that can reasonably said to apply. Please do not say no when you haven't researched a suggestion. The standard SQL syntax when giving a table alias is `<alias> ( <new column names> )`. I don't know what you mean by "two queries".

Comment: [Is there a generic workaround to express a derived column list in Oracle (and MySQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14127707/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@philipxy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404097/philipxy) I have stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14140167/9406165):

```sql
WITH p(name,age) AS (SELECT * FROM PERSON)
SELECT name FROM p WHERE age>=18
```